# How to programmatically create an Azure Automation Account in a specified Resource Group?

Tags: azure, automation, azure-powershell

Is there a way to create a new Azure Automation Account in a specified (existing) Resource Group?

`New-AzureAutomationAccount` cmdlet allows creating a new account, however it forces creation of a new Resource Group named in the following way (`OaasCS<subscription>-<location>`):

```
OaasCSb2f5e86d-f2a9-43cd-872a-22c9b428c2a5-South-Central-US
```

---

Documentation for Azure PowerShell [1.6.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/servicemanagement/azure.automation/v1.6.1/New-AzureAutomationAccount?redirectedfrom=msdn) - [3.0.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/servicemanagement/azure.automation/v3.0.0/new-azureautomationaccount) provides the following syntax for the `New-AzureAutomationAccount` cmdlet (suggesting it is not possible):

> ```
> New-AzureAutomationAccount [-Name] <String> [-Location] <String>
> [-Profile <AzureSMProfile>] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

On the other hand [this documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt244121.aspx)<sup>*</sup> (lists `ResourceGroupName` parameter):

> ```
> New-AzureAutomationAccount [-ResourceGroupName] <String> [-Name] <String>
> [-Location] <String> [-Plan <String> {Free | Basic} ] [-Profile <AzureProfile> ]
> [-Tags <IDictionary> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
> ```

The reality is that `-ResourceGroupName` parameter is not accepted (3.0.0):

```
New-AzureAutomationAccount -Name "ExampleAutomationAccount" -ResourceGroupName "ExampleResourceGroup" -Location $location
```

> New-AzureAutomationAccount : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResourceGroupName'.

---

I am looking for any automated solution, not only PowerShell, however automation seems to be supported only by Azure Portal and Windows PowerShell.

<sup>*</sup> Side question: what is this latter documentation page referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
New-AzureRmAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName 'resourcegroupname' -Location westeurope -Name 'somename'
```

So what is happening - you are trying to create an automation account with an old commandlet (notice the `RM` in mine). Azure Automation doesnt support ASM as of March (can't be sure on this) 2016.